# Error in First Come First Serve (FCFS) CPU Scheduling using C#

Tags: c#, loops, syntax-error, user-input

Can someone please check and fix my code, I'm facing the error below:
main.cs(80,10): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `=', expecting` ,'
main.cs(80,25): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting` ;' or `}' main.cs(89,10): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol` =', expecting `,' main.cs(89,25): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol` )', expecting `;' or` }'
main.cs(96,3): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `char'
Compilation failed: 5 error(s), 0 warnings
compiler exit status 1

My code:

```
// C# program for implementation of FCFS
```

// scheduling
using System;

public class Test
{

```
// Function to find the waiting time for all 
// processes 
 public static void findWaitingTime(int []processes, int n, 
                            int []bt, int[] wt) 
{ 
    // waiting time for first process is 0 
    wt[0] = 0; 

    // calculating waiting time 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        wt[i] = bt[i - 1] + wt[i - 1]; 
    } 
} 

// Function to calculate turn around time 
public  static void findTurnAroundTime(int []processes, int n, 
        int []bt, int []wt, int []tat) { 
    // calculating turnaround time by adding 
    // bt[i] + wt[i] 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        tat[i] = bt[i] + wt[i]; 
    } 
} 

// Function to calculate average time 
    public  static void findavgTime(int []processes, int n, int []bt) 
{ 
    int []wt = new int[n]; 
    int []tat = new int[n]; 
    int total_wt = 0, total_tat = 0; 

    //Function to find waiting time of all processes 
    findWaitingTime(processes, n, bt, wt); 

    //Function to find turn around time for all processes 
    findTurnAroundTime(processes, n, bt, wt, tat); 

    //Display processes along with all details 
    Console.Write("Processes Burst time Waiting"
                +" time Turn around time\n"); 

    // Calculate total waiting time and total turn 
    // around time 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        total_wt = total_wt + wt[i]; 
        total_tat = total_tat + tat[i]; 
        Console.Write(" {0} ", (i + 1)); 
        Console.Write("  {0} ", bt[i]); 
        Console.Write("  {0}", wt[i]); 
        Console.Write("  {0}\n", tat[i]); 
    } 
    float s = (float)total_wt /(float) n; 
    int t = total_tat / n; 
    Console.Write("Average waiting time = {0}", s); 
    Console.Write("\n"); 
    Console.Write("Average turn around time = {0} ", t); 
} 

// Driver code 
public static void Main(String[] args) 
{ 
    do{
        
    // input process 
    int[] processes = new int[100]; 
    Console.WriteLine("How many process? MAX = 100 ");
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    //generate process id
    ( int i = 0; i < n; i++){

         processes[i] = i + 1;

}

    // input Burst time
    int[] burst_time = new int[100];
    Console.WriteLine("Input burst time: ");
    ( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        burst_time[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
        
                findavgTime(processes, n, burst_time); 
        
        Console.WriteLine("Run Again? [Y/N] ")
        char run = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    while(run = Y);

}
```

}

My source:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-fcfs-cpu-scheduling-set-1/

Just wanted to add user input like how many process and the burst time.

Comment: Forgot add for keyword in loop, now I only have error: main.cs(104,3): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `char'

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string` not a `char`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already noticed, you're missing the `for` keyword.
Also, `Console.ReadLine( )` returns a `string` not a `char`.

Should be:

`string run = Console.ReadLine( );`

Or

`var run = Console.ReadLine( );`

Although I think you want to read a specific key so try:

```
var run = Console.ReadKey( );
while ( run.Key == ConsoleKey.Y );
```

I also just noticed that you're using the assignment operator `=` and not the comparison operator `==` in your `do while` loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add for keyword on my loop.